# Using Group By but display all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, grouping

I have this example table:

```
   TABLE A
Field1 | Field2
  X1   |   2
  X2   |   2
  X2   |   3
  X3   |   4
  X4   |   2 
  X3   |   2
```

**Expected Result:**

```
   TABLE A
Field1 | Field2
  X1   |   2
  X2   |   5
  X2   |   5
  X3   |   6
  X4   |   2 
  X3   |   6
```

I want to group all values, but display all rows.
Anyone have some tip to give?

Answer (score 4):

You want window functions, not grouping:

```
SELECT Field1, sum(Field2) OVER (PARTITION BY Field1) AS Field2
FROM yourtable;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're searching for the so called **windowfunctions**.

Here is Microsofts Documentation [Using the OVER clause with aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-using-the-over-clause-with-aggregate-functions)

In your particular example, this will do the job.

```
SELECT SUM(Field2) OVER(PARTITION BY Field1) AS Count FROM TABLE A
```

Answer (score 0):

You must group by field1 to get the sums and join to the table:

```
select 
  t.field1, g.total field2
from tablename t inner join (
  select field1, sum(field2) total
  from tablename
  group by field1
) g on g.field1 = t.field1
```